# What is known about the number of consecutive zeros of the Mertens function?

Tags: number-theory, roots, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-function

The Mertens function M(x) is defined as follows.

---

$$\quad M(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\mu(n)$$

---

The following table lists the consecutive zeros of $M(x)$ of length $l\ge 2$ for $0<x\le 1000$.

---

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 39 & 40 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 149 & 150 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 159 & 160 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 163 & 164 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 231 & 232 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 235 & 236 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 331 & 332 & 333 & \text{} \\
 355 & 356 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 362 & 363 & 364 & \text{} \\
 403 & 404 & 405 & \text{} \\
 407 & 408 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 413 & 414 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 419 & 420 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 422 & 423 & 424 & 425 \\
 427 & 428 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 607 & 608 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 635 & 636 & 637 & \text{} \\
 795 & 796 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 811 & 812 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 823 & 824 & 825 & \text{} \\
 849 & 850 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 883 & 884 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 895 & 896 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 903 & 904 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 915 & 916 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 919 & 920 & \text{} & \text{} \\
\end{array}$$

---

The following table lists the consecutive zeros of $M(x)$ of length $l\ge 5$ for $0<x\le 10,000,000$.

---

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 45371 & 45372 & 45373 & 45374 & 45375 & 45376 \\
 79934 & 79935 & 79936 & 79937 & 79938 & \text{} \\
 246473 & 246474 & 246475 & 246476 & 246477 & \text{} \\
 265471 & 265472 & 265473 & 265474 & 265475 & 265476 \\
 393046 & 393047 & 393048 & 393049 & 393050 & \text{} \\
 973823 & 973824 & 973825 & 973826 & 973827 & 973828 \\
 1246849 & 1246850 & 1246851 & 1246852 & 1246853 & 1246854 \\
 2329323 & 2329324 & 2329325 & 2329326 & 2329327 & 2329328 \\
 2914223 & 2914224 & 2914225 & 2914226 & 2914227 & 2914228 \\
 2944673 & 2944674 & 2944675 & 2944676 & 2944677 & \text{} \\
 3946291 & 3946292 & 3946293 & 3946294 & 3946295 & 3946296 \\
 3946823 & 3946824 & 3946825 & 3946826 & 3946827 & 3946828 \\
 3954247 & 3954248 & 3954249 & 3954250 & 3954251 & 3954252 \\
 7810746 & 7810747 & 7810748 & 7810749 & 7810750 & \text{} \\
 9591602 & 9591603 & 9591604 & 9591605 & 9591606 & \text{} \\
\end{array}$$

---

> **Question (1)**: What is known about the number of consecutive zeros of the Mertens function? For example, is it true there are an infinite number of consecutive zeros of M(x) of length $l$ for any positive integer $l$?

---

> **Question (2)**: Is there a relationship between conjectures on the number of consecutive zeros of the Mertens function and the Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: Question (1): Yes. by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is an $x$ with $x \equiv 0 \mod 2^2$, $x+1 \equiv 0 \mod 3^2$, $x+2 \equiv 0 \mod 5^2$, $x+3 \equiv 0 \mod 7^2$, etc. for how ever many primes you want, then $0 = \mu(x) = \mu(x+1) = \mu(x+2) = \ldots$. Question (2): No.

Comment: @user760870 You are confusing $M(x)$ with $\mu(n)$

Comment: @reuns So is anything known about consecutive zeros of $M(x)$ instead of consecutive zeros of $\mu(n)$?

Comment: Did you see it mentioned in the analytic number theory books ? If so it means there is probably not much to say about it at least with the standard tools.

Comment: @reuns No I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere, but I'm curious about it.

Comment: +1 Interesting question

Comment: For a relation between the Mertens function and the zeroes of the Riemann zeta function see: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UsingZetaZerosToComputeTheMertensFunction/

Comment: I wrote a Mathematica code and can confirm all your results. I have now extended the basic list to 40 Million, and I can add for $l=7$ these two starting numbers : $\{22'898'822,27'975'074\}$