# Is there an unlimited number of sequences of consecutive numbers with $\mu(n)=0$ of any length?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, mobius-function

**EDIT**

I have received interesting comments to my post. Especially the comment of @Martin Hopf showed that this problem is a "classic" and by no means new.

Here is Eric Weissten's article on "**squareful** (nice term!) numbers" https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squareful.html from which you can find the topic exposed.

This article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.3829.pdf is an exhaustive study of the problem.

**Original post**

Consider the subset of the natural numbers $n\ge 1$ which have at least one square prime factor. These can be formally defined by $\mu (n) = 0$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

The first 40 of these are

$$s_{0}=\{4,8,9,12,16,18,20,24,25,27,28,32,36,40,44,45,48,49,50,52,54,56,60,63,64,68,72,75,76,80,81,84,88,90,92,96,98,99,100,104\}$$

Closer inspection of $s_{0}$ shows that there are sequences of consecutive such numbers. We call them *compact sequences*. If sorted by the length $m$ of the compact sequence we find in $s_{0}$ the following

$$m=2: \{8,9\}, \{24,25\}, \{27,28\},\{44,45\},\{48,49\},\{49,50\},\{63,64\},\{75,76\},\{80,81\},\{98,99\},\{99,100\}$$
$$m=3:  \{48,49,50\}, \{98,99,100\}$$

We see that for a given length $m$ there is more than one sequence, and that for the given length 40 of $s_{0}$ there are no sequences with length $m\gt3$.

Prolonging the list $s_0$ we find also longer compact sequences, and, again, for a given length there is more than one sequence.

Quoting only the first member of the first appearance of the corresponding sequence
I found numerically in the format $\{m,\text{first term of first appearance}\}$

$$c=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 8 \\
 3 & 48 \\
 4 & 242 \\
 5 & 844 \\
 6 & 22'020 \\
 7 & 217'070 \\
 8 & 1'092'747 \\
 9 & 8'870'024 \\
10 & 221'167'422\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Remark: this sequence is contained in OEIS (https://oeis.org/A045882). Thanks to @Martin Hopf for pointing this out in a comment.

**Conjecture**

(1)  there is a compact sequences for any given length and
(2)  there are infinitely many compact sequences for any given length

Unfortunately, I was not able to prove or disprove the conjecture. Can you do better?

**Additional question**

(3) can you devise a formula for the first appearance of the compact series for given $m$?

Comment: With the help of the chinese remainder theorem, you can construct an arbitary long chain of consecutive postive integers, none of them squarefree. Just use residue $0$ modulo $4$ , $-1$ modulo $9$ , $-2$ modulo $25$ , $-3$ modulo $49$ and so on.

Comment: More interesting is to find the smallest solution for a given length $n$. I think there is nothing better than brute force.

Comment: @ Peter "More interesting ..." This is my additional question (3). Brute force indeed, it took my weak PC more than two hours to find $c(10)$.

Comment: I noticed that. I just pointed out that it is the more interesting part of the question. Are you interested in the smallest solutions for larger chains ?

Comment: Dear downvoter, I'd appreciate to know the reason.

Comment: @ Peter I thought my list of the $c(m)$ showed my main interest in this problem. I could not go beyond $m=10$ because my algorithm and my PC are not fast enough. Maybe you can push it forward?

Comment: I try to extend the table. There is no reasonable reason for the downvote, but this happens all the time on this site.

Comment: In fact, the last entry even gives a chain of length $11$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120764/discussion-between-dr-wolfgang-hintze-and-peter).

Comment: This question seems to overlap my question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705578.

Comment: Length $13$ occurs at $$466\ 369\ 719\ 316 $$ , but this need not be the smallest solution.

Comment: @ Peter Your $c(13)$ lies slightly above the fitted line. How did you find it? And what about the intermediate case m=12? I suggest to continue the discussion in the chat room, c.f. the link above.

Comment: @ Steven Clark Thank you for the hint. Indeed the algorithmic techniques for consecutive sequences are very similar, and I was able to find two more terms in your case of consecutive zeroes of the Mertens function (see your OP).

Comment: For $c(n)$ with $n \le 18$ see OEIS [A045882](https://oeis.org/A045882).

Comment: @ Martin Hopf Many thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected my wrong remark. Also there are some interesting references in OEIS on the topic.

Comment: Louis Marmet (cited in the OEIS) has done extensive computations on this. It is well worth reading his paper and website if you are interested in this topic (disclaimer: I was one of the contributors).

Comment: @  Erick Wong Thank you very much for the hint. I have browsed through the article showing the impressive cooperation of several authors over many years, and have partly understood why my naive algorithm was bound to fail. Eventually, I'm glad to have found this interesting  problem on my own :-)

Comment: Anything unclear in my answer @Dr.WolfgangHintze

Comment: @ reuns I just saw it. Study is ongoing.

Comment: @ reuns I have (almost) understood that for infinitely many $l$ $|\mu(a_m+lN_m)|=1$ and that for infinitely many $n$ $|\mu(a_m+m+1+nN_m)|=1$ but why are there infinitely many cases where both equalities hold simultaneously ($n=l$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $p_1,\dots,p_m$ be distinct primes. Then, using Chinese remainder there, find $x$ such that:

$$x\equiv  -i \pmod{p_i^2}$$

Then $p_i^2\mid x+i$ for $i=1,\dots,m.$ and there are infinitely many such $x.$

(This assumes you don’t require $\mu(x)\neq 0$ and $\mu(x+m+1)\neq 0.)$

But it does mean we can get arbitrarily long consecutive sequences.

The smallest for a particular $m$ is probably tricky. This is similar to the case where $x+1,x+2,\dots,x+m$ are all non-primes. It is easy to show that such $x$ exists, but it is hard in general to find the smallest $x$ for a given $m.$

Comment: Circle method with $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n(k) e^{2i\pi n z}$, $a_k=|\mu(n)| |\mu(n+k+1)|\prod_{m=1}^k (1-|\mu(n+m)|) $ ? Intuitively it would be easier than weak Goldbach and it should give the asymptotic of  $\sum_{n\le x} a_n(k)$

Answer (score 2):

> There is an elementary way to show that for all $m$ there are infinitely many integers such that $$|\mu(n)|=|\mu(n+m+1)|=1,\qquad  \mu(n+1)=\ldots=\mu(n+m)=0$$

Let $N_m=\prod_{j\le m} p_{j+m}^2$. With the CRT take $$a_m\in [1,N_m], \qquad a_m\equiv -j \bmod p_{j+m}^2,\qquad j \in 1\ldots m$$ so that $\mu(a_m+j+lN_m)=0$ for $j\in 1\ldots m$.

Look at the Dirichlet series $$\begin{eqnarray}F_m(s)&\\ =&\sum_{l\ge 0} |\mu(a_m+lN_m)| (a_m+lN_m)^{-s}+|\mu(a_m+m+1+lN_m)| (a_m+m+1+lN_m)^{-s}\end{eqnarray}$$
Note that $a_m,a_m+m+1$ are coprime with $N_m$. By the orthogonality of Dirichlet characters we have $$F_m(s)= \sum_{\chi \bmod N_m}\frac{\overline{\chi(a_m)}+\overline{\chi(a_m+m+1)}}{\varphi(N_m)}\sum_{n\ge 1}\chi(n)|\mu(n)| n^{-s} $$
For $\chi$ a non trivial Dirichlet character, $\sum_{n\ge 1}\chi(n)|\mu(n)| n^{-s}$ is holomorphic at $s=1$.

Whence the asymptotic as $s\to 1$ is determined by the trivial character $1_{\gcd(n,N_m)=1}$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}F_m(s)&\sim& \frac{2}{\varphi(N_m)}\sum_{n\ge 1,\gcd(n,N_m)=1} |\mu(n)| n^{-s}\\&=&\frac{2}{\varphi(N_m)} \frac1{\prod_{p\ |\ N_m} (1+p^{-s})} \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}\\&\sim& \frac{2}{N_m} \frac1{\prod_{p\ | \ N_m} (1-p^2)} \frac{1}{\zeta(2)}\zeta(s)\end{eqnarray}$$

Since $\frac1{\prod_{p\ | \ N_m} (1-p^2)}\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}>1/2$ this implies that for infinitely many $l$ $$|\mu(a_m+lN_m)|=|\mu(a_m+m+1+lN_m)|=1$$
so that $a_m+lN_m,\ldots, a_m+m+1+lN_m$ is our chain of length $m$.

Comment: Sounds about right.  I suspect there is a way to rephrase this argument in terms of relative density of sequences, so that it feels more elementary.

Comment: Amazingly the same approach fails completely to find arbitrary long runs of squarefree numbers.

Comment: Lol, but you can at least find arbitrarily long strings of admissible “constellations”, analogous to how a prime triplet is defined as $(p,p+\cdot, p+6)$ rather than $(p,p+2,p+4)$.

Comment: I think the circle method solves all the admissible motives, though it is unclear to me where admissible comes into play.

Comment: @ reuns +1 Looks like a great proof for chains of exactly lengths $m$, i.e. $\mu\ne 0$ beyond ends of the chain. But, honestly, it is not elementary enough for my current level of knowledge.

Comment: Did you see Dirichlet characters already? We need it to say that $\sum_n \chi(n)|\mu(n)|n^{-s} = \frac{L(s,\chi)}{L(2s,\chi^2)}$ is analytic at $s=1$ (because $L(s,\chi)$ doesn't have a pole at $s=1$ in contrary to $\zeta(s)$)

Comment: @ reuns Hopefully, I can take the opportunity of this problem to finally delve into Dirichlet characters. Also the circle method is new to me. Many reuns hints for me :-)

Comment: @ reuns Shouldn't the last line read "so that $a_m+1+lN_m,\ldots, a_m+m+lN_m$ is our chain [of squareful numbers] of length $m$"?